# Photoshop Javascript: How to Change the brush Mode with javascript?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

really a beginner at photoshop scripting.

Right now I'm making some scripts that are useful to me with my workflow like visibility toggle stuffs.

What I really wanted to know now is how to change not the 'Layer Blending Mode', but the 'Brush Mode'(like normal, multiply, clear, etc...) using javascript. I can't seem to find some resources to control the brush modes.

Hope you guys can help me and shed some light in this matter.

Comment: You can't. There is no recording of brush type position, stroke or mode for any brushes. What are you trying to do beyond that?

Comment: Thank you for that info. Seems like I need to look for another way to get to what I wanted. planning to create a toggle for normal and clear brush mode so I can use the same brush to add and remove pixels more intuitively. I know there is a shortcut for brush modes but I find it awkward in the hands and disrupts the spontaneous feeling when sketching

Comment: Sadly, brushes and strokes are beyond the power of Photoshop Scripting. The best thing you can do is make several bushes - but you'll have to tweak them every time you swap them out, which isn't what you're after.

Comment: You can however write scripts to toggle a layer on and off -given a set of parameters (defined within an array - for example) which you can then record the script as an action to bind it to a hot key

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, here's a snippet I pieced together, it works by creating an action and executing it. (Normally changing a brush mode can't be done with regular actions, but it does work like this in CC 2017)

```
var bmsS = ["normal", "dissolve", "behind", "clearEnum",
            "darken", "multiply", "colorBurn", "linearBurn", "darkerColor",
            "lighten", "screen", "colorDodge", "linearDodge", "lighterColor",
            "overlay", "softLight", "hardLight", "vividLight", "linearLight", "pinLight", "hardMix",
            "difference", "exclusion", "blendSubtraction", "blendDivide",
            "hue", "saturation", "color", "luminosity",  ]; 

// Select the paint brush tool
var idslct = stringIDToTypeID( "select" );
var desc226 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idnull = stringIDToTypeID( "null" );
var ref170 = new ActionReference();
var idPbTl = stringIDToTypeID( "paintbrushTool" );
ref170.putClass( idPbTl );
desc226.putReference( idnull, ref170 );
executeAction( idslct, desc226, DialogModes.NO );

// blend mode
var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
var idset = stringIDToTypeID( "set" );
//alert(desc.getEnumerationValue(stringIDToTypeID("mode")));
desc.putEnumerated(stringIDToTypeID("mode"), stringIDToTypeID("blendModel"), stringIDToTypeID("clearEnum"));
desc226.putObject( stringIDToTypeID( "to" ), stringIDToTypeID( "null" ), desc);
executeAction( idset, desc226, DialogModes.NO );
```

Comment: Note however that this will break the brush if it uses a sampled tip.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same limitations and used AutoHotkey to get around them.

This script sets Shift+e to Alt+Shift+r (clear brush mode) and Shift+r to Alt+Shift+n (normal brush mode).

Download AutoHotkey, save the script below as a .ahk, and double click it.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Photoshop

+e::
    Send, {Shift Down}{Alt Down}r
    Send, {Shift Up}{Alt Up}
Return

+r::
    Send, {Shift Down}{Alt Down}n
    Send, {Shift Up}{Alt Up}
Return

#IfWinActive
```

If you want it to run on startup, you can save it to the windows startup folder:

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\brushBlendModes.ahk
```